# JdbcTemplate batchUpdate is it possible to use a sequence in the insert?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Is it possible to use a sequence in the insert of a call to the `batchUpdate` method?
I've not found anything on this subject.

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
    "INSERT INTO TUR1HV01.UR1_CP_GOR (id, GOR_NAME)  values (select TUR1HV01.SEQ_CP_GOR_MODEL.nextval from dual, ?)",
    gorList,
    10000,
    (ps, argument) -> {
        ps.setString(1, argument.getGorName());
 });
```

Exception:
`Caused by: Error : 936, Position : 56, Sql = INSERT INTO TUR1HV01.UR1_CP_GOR (id, GOR_NAME)  values (select TUR1HV01.SEQ_CP_GOR_MODEL.nextval from dual, :1 ), OriginalSql = INSERT INTO TUR1HV01.UR1_CP_GOR (id, GOR_NAME)  values (select TUR1HV01.SEQ_CP_GOR_MODEL.nextval from dual, ?), Error Msg = ORA-00936: missing expression`

shlould I use a trigger insetad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values (TUR1HV01.SEQ_CP_GOR_MODEL.nextval, ?)
```

should work.